# Verifying the Model generated by the classifier

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I am using Mahout Naive bayes classification algorithm to classify the input documents to known categories.

I am able to build the model using mahout commands.

- mahout seq2sparse
- mahout split
- mahout trainnb
- mahout testnb

Test results looks good.

Now, I would like to verify my model with real data.

I am trying below command to verify the ouptut:

```
 mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.Classify \
  -m /data/model/ \
  --classify  /data/input.txt \
  --encoding UTF-8 \
  --analyzer org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DefaultAnalyzer \
  --defaultCat unknown \
  -ng 1 \
  -type bayes \
  -source hdfs
```

This command is failing with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.Classify".

I have set the mahout core jar and other mahout jars in the classpath. I am using Mahout 0.9.

How to run the classifier in Mahout 0.9 ?

Comment: the jar where this class is located should be in your classpath somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I have the Jar in the classpath.Looks like "org.apache.mahout.classifier.Classify" class not available in Mahout 0.9. So question is how we can validate the model from the command line ?

Comment: Is testnb not doing the verification you need?

Comment: In any case, you seem to be right, there is no such class in Mahout 0.9

Comment: Yes. What I am looking for is every time when i get new data..I will run "Classify" command on  new data and classify command should tell me which category data belongs to.